# Xaramin SDK path in settings different from one in SDK Manager

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk

Edit: I'm an idiot and if you're looking for the answer to this the sdk in setting and SDK Manager are the same and your SDK in setting must be incorrect.

[image: Image displays sdk path being different in settings than SDK managers.]

How can I fix this. I have changed SDK path in setting multiple times and I can't download anything because it's says SDK path is incorrect. Also same incorrect SDK path in manager and correct one in settings when in Visual Studio. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Did u run SDK manager from a command line/batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths are the same.

`C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROID~1`

Is just a silly way of using paths in Windows file systems to avoid having spaces, special characters and too long path names.

So `PROGRA~2` means `Program Files (x86)` as it is the second occurance of a folder starting with *progra*. The middle part of the path is obvious. `ANDROI~1` translates into `android-sdk` as it is the first folder starting with *androi* in that folder.

So in the end you have the path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`

Comment: Oh my thank you and sorry for wasting your time I guess I must recheck the path again.